# Expose Service Layer directly in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Last couple of days I've wondering something: I think it's a nice practice to make controller layer as thin as possible. Just the mappings methods and a single line calling injected service. Nothing more. And develop all the logic in the service itself.

But that idea drove me to another place? It would be possible to expose the service layer directly? I mean: "hack" the spring framework in a way that I only have one controller and using some kind of "convention over configuration" philosophy, define the following uri formats:

http://server:port/api/MyServiceClass/MyPublicMethod

All data would be sent by post and developers only will need to focus on delivering @Service 's and be more "productive" ...

Do you think this could be a good idea? Pros/Cons?

Do you know if there is anybody out there doing something like this?

Any help/ideas/suggestions will be grateful

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your project is really simple, you can even let the user just write sql to access data base. What I mean is the mvc layers are used to decouple project logic... It's not fixed...The architecture depends on your project

Comment: Yep but..imagine a huge legacy project, with 30-40 services that want to move to new Spring versions. If we think that thin controllers are fine... What if we expose services directly? Thanks for your response!

Comment: And... In fact the controller layer would still exists (the "hack"), but no line of code would be neccesary to included by the developer in order  to expose the services