# How to expose service with spring 5?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, service

I want to expose service with Spring framework (not with spring boot). Then i can use the service to feed a dashboard. Charts in the dashboard need data with json format. My question is similar to this topic but with more question about code.[question]: [Expose Service Layer directly in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719068/expose-service-layer-directly-in-spring-mvc)

I first did the model, repository to access database. I am using Hibernate and MySQL. I run my application with a class containing the main method. Then i tried to add a rest controller to access the method findAll. But when i deployed the application on Tomcat, i only get the message 404 not found.

This is my first controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/fruit")
public class FruitController {

    @Autowired
    private IFruitRepository fruitRepo = new FruitRepository();


    @RequestMapping( value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public @ResponseBody List<Port> getFruit() {
        List<Fruit> res = fruitRepo.findAll();
        return res;
    }
}
```

this is the interface

```java
public interface IFruitRepository {
    Boolean create(Fruit p);
    Fruit findById(int id);
    List<Fruit> findAll();
    Fruit update(Fruit f);
    boolean delete(int id);
}
```

this is the implementation of findAll method

```
public List<Fruit> findAll(){
    List<Fruit> à_retourner = new ArrayList<>();

    try (SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Fruit");
        à_retourner = query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception _ findAll _ Fruit : " + e);
    }
    return à_retourner;
}
```

EDIT:
web .xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

dispacher-servlet.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

applicationcontext.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

Should i add servlet , dispacher servlet , application context to find the resource through URI ?

Comment: To see what is happening you should post your web.xml to see if there is any errors with the spring mvc servlet dispatcher or any other thing

Comment: i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is exactly the url you are using to test the service but if you are trying to invoke /fruit/all, it won't work because the servlet dispatcher is configured to handle request that ends with .form. To make it work you should change the url-pattern of the servlet dispatcher to something like /fruit/*